# Azure AD OAuth2 No permission to access user information

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am getting this error when trying to get the Token from Azure Active Directory. I have got the code and everything looks great, but now I am getting this?

I have tried to give the application all kinds of different permissions?

```
Access Denied  
{
   "error":"invalid_grant",
   "error_description":"AADSTS65001: No permission to access user information is configured for '{applicationId}' application, or it is expired or revoked.\r\nTrace ID: 0493ca6a-442d-4f68-9bb7-bc754896aac1\r\nCorrelation ID: e7a4981a-febb-49a0-b016-57f1d863a2bb\r\nTimestamp: 2015-01-29 09:36:07Z",
   "error_codes":[65001],
   "timestamp":"2015-01-29 09:36:07Z",
   "trace_id":"0493ca6a-442d-4f68-9bb7-bc754896aac1",
   "correlation_id":"e7a4981a-febb-49a0-b016-57f1d863a2bb",
   "submit_url":null,
   "context":null
}
```

Comment: Can you add what permissions you've configured for the app? Also, please add the auth request response and token request. Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue? We are experiencing the exact same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this won't work, we choose to use OpenIdConnect instead which worked fine.